# For loop won't run when comparing length of Vector to a negative number in C++

Tags: c++

I have a pair of nested for loops and I am attempting to print the following structure:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 
0 - - - - - 
1 - - - - - 
2 - - - - - 
3 - - - - - 
4 - - - - -
```

If I attempt to initialize the row counter of the outer loop to -1, and compare it to the length of the vector using .length(), the outer loop simply does not run. I've tested this by putting print statements within the outer loop and they never get executed. My compiler also issues the following warning: `warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<std::vector<char> >::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]`
I attempted to change the row counter from an int to a long unsigned int, and while that suppresses the warning message, the loop still won't run. What is the reason for this behavior and how can I resolve it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print_board(vector<vector<char>> board)
{
    int row, col;

    cout << "  ";
    for (row = -1; row < board.size(); row++)
    {
        if (row > -1)
            cout << row << " ";

        for (col = 0; col < board[row].size(); col++)
        {
            if (row == -1)
                cout << col << " "; 
            else
                cout << board[row][col] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int max_rows = 5;
    vector<vector<char>> player_one_board(max_rows, vector<char>(max_rows, '-'));

    print_board(player_one_board);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A vector does not support negative indexing. `board[-1]` is undefined behavior. Valid indices are `0 .. size -1`

Comment: As a hint, try converting -1 to an unsigned int.

Comment: If you want to print the row number, why not simply do this first when the index is `0`?

Comment: Why not simply -- `if (row == 0) { do something to print the special row on the first line; continue; }`?  There is no need for `-1` anywhere in the code.

Comment: The return type of `std::vector::size()` is an unsigned integral type.   Comparing that type with `-1` promotes `-1` to the same (unsigned) type for the purpose of comparison.  `-1` when converted to an unsigned type yields the maximum value that unsigned type can represent (i.e. a large positive value).   That value cannot be less than any value that `.size()` may return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're doing is printing out the board, you really shouldn't be starting at -1, but 0 instead.  That is:

```
std::cout << "  ";
for (std::size_t col = 0; col < board[0].size(); ++col) {
   std::cout << col << " ";
}

std::cout << std::endl;

for (std::size_t row = 0; row < board.size(); ++row) {
    std::cout << row << " ";
    for (std::size_t col = 0; col < board[row].size(); ++ col) {
        std::cout << board[row][col] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vector can not consist from less than 0 elements. Initialize row with 0, or skip loop for col using continue if row is less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

The warning basically tells you everything: `board.size()` is unsigned, so should be `row`. When you supress the warning, the problem now isn't the comparison, but how `row` is initialized with `-1`. It really shouldn't be, because it's unsigned, it can't hold `-1`. Instead, it silently gets initialized with some positive number. At this point, it's really C++'s fault that you don't get another warning or error. Its type system is kind of weak because of C legacy.

The solution here is to keep `row` unsigned and express your logic differently, without `-1`.